# Surjectivity of an operator on $L^2(R)$ defined as identity minus convolution

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm having trouble with the following exercise. Define $T:L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ by means of the formula

$$(Tf)(x)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x+y)dy.$$

I proved that, for all $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, $Tf$ is a continuous function and $||Tf||_2\le||f||_2$, with equality iff $f(x)=0$ almost everywhere.

Then there is the following question, on which I'm stuck: **is $S:=I-T$ surjective?** Here, $I$ is the identity operator. This should be doable at the level of "Papa Rudin".

**Edit:**
Thanks to the last paragraph in @FTP's great answer, I think I have an idea for a more "elementary" (but more complicated) solution.

We know that $X:=L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Suppose $S$ is surjective. Since $S$ is injective and continuous, by the Open Mapping Theorem, it follows that $S$ is invertible.

Now, let $g\in X$ and $f=S^{-1}g$. By density, there is $\{f_n\}\subset X$ such that $f_n\to f$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Write $g_n=Sf_n$. Since each $f_n$ is integrable, it follows by Fubini-Tonelli that each $g_n$ is integrable, and we actually have

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}g_n(x)dx\int_{\mathbb{R}}(Sf_n)(x)dx=0.\quad (*)$$

Also, by the continuity of $S$, we obtain that $g_n\to g$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

**If we choose $g$ very nice with positive integral, can we obtain contradiction with equation (*)?**

Comment: Hint: open mapping theorem

Comment: @TheOscillator Thanks for the hint. I tried using the open mapping theorem to show that $S$ is not surjective, but I could not find a suitable open subset. I will try it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator $T$ is the convolution of $f$ with function $g=\chi_{[-1, 0]}$. Therefore, on the Fourier transform side we have $\widehat{Tf} = \hat f\hat g$. Here
$$
\hat g(\xi) = \int_{-1}^0 e^{-2\pi i \xi x}\,dx = \frac{e^{2\pi i \xi}-1}{2\pi \xi i}
\tag1 $$
Notably, $\hat g$ is smooth and $\hat g(0)=1$. We don't really need (1) to see this, the obvious properties that $g$ has compact support and $\int g=1$ are enough.

So, $I-T$ is $\hat f\mapsto (1-\hat g)\hat f$ on the Fourier side. This is clearly injective, as $1-\hat g \ne 0$ almost everywhere. If this map was  surjective, it'd be invertible (open mapping theorem), and the inverse can be nothing else but  $\hat f\mapsto (1-\hat g)^{-1} \hat f$. But   the latter is not a bounded operator on $L^2$  since $(1-\hat g)^{-1} \notin L^\infty$.

#### Without OMT

One can avoid the open mapping theorem and simply present a function $\phi\in L^2$ such that $\phi/(1-\hat g)\notin L^2$. For example, 
$$
\phi(\xi) = \max(0, |\xi|^{-1/3}-1)
$$ 
would do. Let $\check \phi$ be the inverse Fourier transform of $\phi$; then $\check \phi\notin \operatorname{ran}(I-T)$. Indeed, if $\check \phi = (I-T)f$, then $\hat f(\xi) = \phi(\xi)/(1-\hat g(\xi))$ which is not in $L^2$.

#### Without Fourier transform

Informally, the above is a long-winded justification of "since $Tf$ and $f$ have the same integral, the integral of $f-Tf$ must be zero". The preceding sentence doesn't make a proof because $f$ and $Tf$ need not be in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. But one can consider the regularization 
$$
\lim_{c\to 0^+} \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-cx^2} (f(x)-Tf(x))\,dx
\tag 2$$
and show (with some help from Fubini) that (2) is $0$ for every $f\in L^2$. Then it becomes obvious that, for example, any positive function cannot be in $\operatorname{ran}(I- T)$.

Comment: Just for the purpose of citation, the corollary of the open mapping theorem that was used here is sometimes called the bounded inverse theorem and can be found in Rudin's Functional Analysis as Corollary 2.12.

Comment: This answer is excellent, thank you very much. This was a little harder than I thought. This is a question from an old Analysis qualifying exam from my university, and typically, this last items with an interrogation mark are usually easier than the items before. Probably, it would never ocurred to me neither the couterexample nor using Fourier. (Sorry my english, i'm not a native speaker).